# Problem with ImplicitRegion

Tags: plotting

Mathematica draws the domain

```
RegionPlot[3^Sqrt[x] - 3^(2 Sqrt[y]) >= -Sqrt[x] + 2 Sqrt[y] && 
 x^2 + y^2 <= 9 + 2 x y, {x, -0.1, 5}, {y, -0.1, 2}, PlotPoints -> 30]
```

[image]
which is the triangle with the vertices at $(0,0),(3,0),$ and $(4,1),$ though Mathematica has problems with

```
Reduce[3^Sqrt[x]-3^(2*Sqrt[y]) >= 2*Sqrt[y]-Sqrt[x] && x^2 + y^2 <= 9 + 2*x*y,{x, y},Reals]
```

> Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce.

whereas a simple piecewise expression is expected.

Applying `ImplicitRegion` , I draw a blank:

```
k =ImplicitRegion[3^Sqrt[x]-3^(2*Sqrt[y])>= 2*Sqrt[y]-Sqrt[x]&&x^2+y^2 <= 9 + 2*x*y,{x, y}];
Region[k]
```

produces no any  plot and

```
Area[k]
```

> Area::nmet: Unable to compute the area of region ImplicitRegion[3^Sqrt[x]-3^(2 Sqrt[y])>=-Sqrt[x]+2 Sqrt[y]&&x^2+y^2<=9+2 x y,{x,y}].

or is running for ages.

Its discretization does not work:

```
DiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[3^Sqrt[x] - 3^(2*Sqrt[y]) >= 2*Sqrt[y] - Sqrt[x] && 
   x^2 + y^2 <= 9 + 2*x*y, {x, y}], {{-0.1, 5}, {-0.1, 2}}]
```

> DiscretizeRegion::drf: DiscretizeRegion was unable to discretize the region ImplicitRegion[<<2>>].

The question is: how to programmatically calculate the area of the domain under consideration?

Comment: Workaround: `k = DiscretizeRegion[
  ImplicitRegion[
   3^Sqrt[x] - 3^(2*Sqrt[y]) >= 2*Sqrt[y] - Sqrt[x] && 
    x^2 + y^2 <= 9 + 2*x*y, {x, y}], {{0, 5}, {0, 2}}]; Area[k]`

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk: It does not work on my comp, running for ages. I use 11.3 on Windows 10 32 bit.

Comment: I have MMA `11.3` on Windows 8.1 64 bit and works fine.MMA answer give with about `0.000432443 second`.I tried on https://develop.wolframcloud.com and work fine to.

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk: Thank you.  Your code produces 1.5 on my comp in a dozen of minutes.